# SQL Pivot on non-numeric values on multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following data:

| Employee | Date | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Emp 1 | 01/01/2023 | 1.50 |
| Emp 1 | 01/01/2023 | 7.5 LB |
| Emp 1 | 02/01/2023 | 0.00 |
| Emp 1 | 02/01/2023 | 1.5 LB |
| Emp 1 | 03/01/2023 | 7.5 LB |

I would like to pivot the table such that for a day where there's multiple records, each record should be on its own row, as follow:

| Employee | 01/01/2023 | 02/01/2023 | 03/01/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Emp 1 | 1.50 | 0.00 |  |
| Emp 1 | 7.5 LB | 1.5LB | 7.5 LB |

Before I had multiple values per day, my query was as follows:

```
Select Employee, Date, case when Type = 'A' then Amount else Amount + ' ' +  'LB' end as Amount from Table1 
Pivot (max(Amount) for Dates in ([1],[2],[3],....[30],[31]) as PivotTable
```

Can you please assist on how I can achieve this?

Comment: I would *strongly* recommend you do this in your presentation layer, if I am honest. You would have to use dynamic SQL here, and the lack of a column to denote what an `Amount` represents poses *problems*.

Comment: You could separate amounts based on Type..`select p.*
from
(
select Employee, Date, case when Type = 'A' then Amount else Amount + ' ' +  'LB' end as Amount,
  case when Type = 'A' then 1 else 2 end as tprn
from table1
) as t
pivot(max(Amount) for Date in ([01/01/2023], [02/01/2023], [03/01/2023])) as p`

Comment: @Lavie : Are you sure, you using `sql-server-2008-r2` ?

Comment: Sorry its 2016 not 2008. I picked the wrong tag

Comment: How do you determine which row a value goes on? How many rows can there be for each Employee, can the amounts that only contain numeric values always be treated differently?